# Convert all objects in a list to a child class.

Tags: python, list, object

I have 2 classes, a parent and a class which inherits from it. In a list I have an arbitrary number of objects of the parent class, however. I need to convert them all to the child class.

A really simplified version of the code would look like this:

```
class parent(object):
    def __init__():
        self.a = 1

class child(parent):
    def __init__():
        self.b = 2

list_of_objects = []

for x in range(0, 10)
    a = parent()
    list_of_objects.append(a)
```

I'm pretty sure I could convert the objets 1 by 1 in a loop using the following line.

```
a.__dict__ = b.__dict__
```

But is there a way to convert the whole list at once?

Comment: Beyond "convert them all to the child class", what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: jon, the objects are coming from another program which I am accessing via an API. I need to do other things with those objects which the base object will not allow, so I need to convert them somehow. The child object is more suitable so I need to convert to that

Comment: `__init__()` should be `__init__(self)`.

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand could you have a `@classmethod` on the `child` like `def from_parent(cls, parent_instance):`? Just replacing the `__dict__` means that any `child` attributes or methods will be gone, although `__dict__.update()` might work.

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand So the both classes  *and*  the API you use are beyond your control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `a.__dict__ = b.__dict__`, unless the instance attributes are added dynamically - `__dict__` is only used for dynamically added objects. If you're sure the classes are pure python and the internal object properties are named similarly, you *could* `a.__class__=b.__class__`.

If you're able to create instances of `child`, a somewhat cleaner way may be to define a function that creates a `child` instance from a `parent` instance. You can avoid the loop by using `map` or list comprehensions:

```
def parent_to_child(parent):
    newchild= child()
    newchild.property= parent.property
    #...

list_of_children= map(parent_to_child, list_of_parents)
```